# AWS: Change S3 filenames to lowercase through CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lowercase

I have (unknowingly) uploaded files to my S3 bucket where most of them have uppercase letters.
Is there a command that I can use to rename/change their names to all lowercase.
I need to do a bulk change and cannot use specific filenames since the change needs to happen for all the files in the bucket. There are no sub-folders and all the files are in the root.

Answer (score 2):

You may run something like below. Replace `bucket-name` with your S3 bucket name.

> for i in $( aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name | awk '{print $4}' ); do aws s3 mv s3://bucket-name/$i s3://bucket-name/`echo $i | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`; done

Comment: Can I limit the action to say top 10 or something in order to avoid a rollback in case something fails?

Comment: Yes add `head -10` to the file listing part - `$( aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name | awk '{print $4}' | head -10);`

Comment: to get the next 10 lines use `| head -20 | tail -10` and increase the count of head accordingly ..

Comment: Thanks Prabu, However the "for i" is giving me an error. Is it possible that I am using a different version of the AWS CLI?

Comment: Not sure this should work on all linux/unix machine. Why don't you try with simpler version to test on local only  **for i in $( ls ); do echo $i in lower case is \`echo $i | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'\`; done**

Comment: Looks like the AWS's CLI is not recognizing this command. Same happened for me when I used while as a loop too

Comment: did certain improvements. 1) --recursive to include subfolders 2) handle spaces in file names 3) ignore files already in lower case .  SCRIPT:  `IFS=$'\n'; DQT='"'; for f in $(aws s3 ls --recursive s3://mybucket | awk '{$1=$2=$3=""}1' |  sed 's/\s\+//' ); do sr="${DQT}s3://mybucket/$f${DQT}"; tr="${DQT}s3://mybucket/\`echo $f | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'\`${DQT}" ; if [ "$sr" != "$tr" ]; then cmnd=$(echo aws s3 mv "$sr" "$tr") ; eval $cmnd; fi done`

Comment: To improve on the answer a little bit, based on the man page of `tr` you should prefer this `tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"` over the one in the answer `tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'` since it works correctly in all locales.